# DamagedFontException thrown when initialising PDFont (Apache PDFBox)

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using Apache PDFBox 2.0.2 and FontBox 1.8.5. I'm trying to write text to a PDF document, but I keep getting the same exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/fontbox/type1/DamagedFontException
```

Underneath the stack trace it says the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.fontbox.type1.DamagedFontException
```

I'm using NetBeans, and have added the JARs for both PDFBox and FontBox correctly - everything else that uses their functionality works fine. The relevant code snippet:

```
// Create new document and page
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
doc.addPage(page);

PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;   // The exception is thrown here

// Write to document
PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
stream.beginText();
stream.setFont(font, 12);
stream.drawString(pdfText);
stream.endText();
```

It's practically a paraphrased copy of the PDFBox Hello World example, so I can't understand what the problem is. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

> I'm using Apache PDFBox 2.0.2 and FontBox 1.8.5.

...

> and have added the JARs for both PDFBox and FontBox correctly

No you haven't added it correctly. Use PDFBox 2.0.2 with FontBox 2.0.2, not 1.8.5 (which is two years old). Alternatively, download the PDFBox app which has both. Even better, use maven which will take care of dependencies for you.